# How can you quickly tell if a cubic polynomial gives an injective function?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, cubics, discriminant

Given a cubic polynomial $p = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ with real coefficients, is there a quick way to determine if the function $p \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is injective? Does anyone know if there is a clean classification of cubic polynomials that induce injective functions?

Comment: It is injective iff it is everywhere increasing or decreasing iff $p'(x)$ has no real zeros. You only need to calculate the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial $p'(x)$.

Comment: It can still be injective if $p'$ has exactly one real zero (e.g. $p(x)= x^3$)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen , Ha thanks. I totally forgot that calculus is a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked for a **quick** way, certainly the discriminant of the first derivative is the way to go, but that can be boiled down a bit further.

From $3ax^2+2bx+c=0$ we obtain the requirement $D=4(b^2-3ac)\le0$ which reduces to the quick test

$$ b^2\le 3ac $$

for $p$ to be injective.